# Spring Security Hibernate MySQL Uzivatel(User) is not mapped

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I implemented Spring Security with Hibernate but It's not working. I got this error:

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Uzivatel is not mapped [from Uzivatel u where u.username = :username]
org.hibernate.hql.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:158)
org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:87)
...
```

Where can be mistake?

My UzivatelDaoImpl.class

```
@Repository
public class UzivatelDaoImpl implements UzivatelDao{
@Autowired  
    private SessionFactory session;

private Session openSession() {
    return session.getCurrentSession();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public Uzivatel getUzivatel(String username) {
    List<Uzivatel> uzivatelList = new ArrayList<Uzivatel>();
    Query query = openSession().createQuery("from Uzivatel u where u.username = :username");
    query.setParameter("username", username);
    uzivatelList = query.list();
    if (uzivatelList.size() > 0)
        return (Uzivatel) uzivatelList.get(0);
    else
        return null;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you don't mapped entity in hibernate.cfg.xml or you not have @Entity annotation in Uzivatel class.